# Assign ip address to eth0 within docker container after I moved eth0 to a new namespace

Tags: docker, linux-networking, docker-compose, network-namespace

Trying to implement WireGuard VPN killswitch using this tutorial [The New Namespace Solution](https://www.wireguard.com/netns/#the-new-namespace-solution)

But after I moving eth0 from init namespace to second namespace it lost assigned ip address:

```
ip netns add physical
ip link set eth0 netns physical
4030df9c72c3:/# ip netns exec physical ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
3: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/tunnel6 :: brd :: permaddr 42b1:64fa:917a::
60: eth0@if61: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:b0:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

The steps provided in tutorial don't applicable to my scenario, it's a docker and alpine image they suppose that I work from physical machine:

```
# ip netns exec physical dhcpcd wlan0
# ip netns exec physical wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
# ip -n physical addr add 192.168.12.52/24 dev eth0
```

So, my question how can I reassign ip address to `eth0` after it has been moved from `init` namespace to new namespace `physical` in my case.

Comment: Why doesn't `ip -n physical addr add a.b.c.d/f dev eth0` work? Does it give an error? What do you see if you run `ip -n physical addr`?